# How does Java store Negative numbers in an Integer Variable?

Tags: java

How does this snippet of code prints "-511" as the output on the console?

```
   class Test
   {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = -0777; 
    System.out.printf("%d",i);
    }
   }
```

Is it to do with the way Java stores Negative numbers?

Comment: That prints -63 for me :)

Comment: Sorry it was a typo error. For -077 it prints -63. I have updated the snipet. But doesnt matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Integer numbers prefixed with `0` are [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numbers. To use decimal numbers remove the `0` prefix:

```
int i = -777;
```

Answer (score 4):

Numbers starting with `0` are treated as being in octal by Java.  `-077` is equivalent to `-63`, which is what I get when I run your program.

Answer (score 2):

When a number in java code starts with a 0, it interprets it as octal format